# Solving ODE $y''+y'-2y=0$ using power series.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I have to solve

> $$y''+y'-2y=0$$
>   with $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=1$.

Using
$$y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}$$
I got $a_{0}=0,a_{1}=1$ and
$$a_{n}=\frac{(n+1)(a_{n+1}+(n+2)a_{n+2})}{2}$$
And I really don't know what can I do now. I mean: is there some recursive thing? I calculated the value of $a_{2},a_{3},a_{4},a_{5}$ and $a_{6}$ and I couldn't see anything.

Comment: What are the values for $a_{2}, a_{3}, a_{4}, a_{5}$ and $a_{6}$?
Not necessarilly you must find a pattern

Comment: Well, the are "weird", I mean, I really couldn't find anything between them. So could I leave the solution as I described?

Comment: Perhaps having a solution would help. The characteristic equation is $r^2 + r - 2 = 0$ so that $r = -2$ or $r = 1$ so that a general solution is $c_1 e^{-2x} + c_2 e^{x}$. Since the solution is so simple, I presume you are supposed to simplify the coefficients you get

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beside the solution suggested by Brevan Ellefsen, you could rewrite
$$a_{n}=\frac{(n+1)(a_{n+1}+(n+2)a_{n+2})}{2}$$ as
$$2a_n=(n+1)a_{n+1}+(n+1)(n+2)a_{n+2}$$ Muliply each side by $n!$ and simplify to get
$$2\,n!\, a_n=(n+1)!\,a_{n+1}+(n+2)!\, a_{n+2}$$Now, define $b_n=n! \, a_n$ to get
$$2 b_n=b_{n+1}+b_{n+2}$$ for which the characteristic equation is $$2=r+r^2\implies (r-1)(r+2)=0$$ I am sure that you can take it from here and get a simple expression for $a_n$.

Comment: But why did you get a characteristic equation to the coeficients? Can you do that?

Comment: @mvfs314. How do you solve $2 b_n=b_{n+1}+b_{n+2}$ ?

Comment: I don't know hahaha is this an ODE?